# Changing Only Toggled Div Color On Jquery Click

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm customizing the Variations Style in Wordpress Using Custom CSS & Jquery.

I have a clicked event on DIV which the toggle is opened and I want to change the title color but only where the toggle is on.

Here is my Code

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){

if ( $('.tm-collapse-wrap').is(':visible') ) {
    //do something
  $('.btnClass').css('color','black'); 
  $('.cs-price').css('color','black');  
  $('.cs-price').css('border-color','black');  
        $('.mkSize').css('color','#8e8e8e');  
        $('.tm-description').css('color','black');  


}
  else if ( $('.tm-collapse-wrap').is(':hidden') ){
      $('.btnClass').css('color','#005267');  
      $('.cs-price').css('color','#005267');  
      $('.cs-price').css('border-color','#005267');  
      $('.mkSize').css('color','#4683939e');  
      $('.tm-description').css('color','#005267');  


  }
}
```

The issue is it will change all section colors. I want to change it only where only the toggle is on.

[CHECK Website URL](https://weartmotivated.com/product/crimson-palms-hotel)

Comment: the details tag is more useful for that: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_details.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand what [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) method does. It returns true if at least one of the selected elements has the property. With `$('.tm-collapse-wrap').is()` you select ALL divs, no matter if they are visible or not.

You change a class property of a class ALL divs have (like .btnClass), those with collapsed and those with expanded details. If you click ONE div, you change colors to ALL divs.

You have to change only the properties of clicked divs. Inside click() function, you can access the current clicked element by `$(this)` and children of that by `$(this).children("selector")`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Actually, I'm new to jquery. I used this to change the color  ` $(this).css('color','#005267');  ` but on next div click previous click color need to revert back to black

Comment: can you post your new code? what isn't working? I looked on your page and color returns to black when closing the div.

Comment: Check the above jquery code which i am using. Currently On Div Click the Div open and color chnage and on again click the div closes and color revert back to black. But if you click one div and then click next div without closing the previous div then color wont chnages. This is the issue now i am facing.

Comment: This code is not efficient as just copied lines 4 and 5 which causes the same code is executed successively 2 times (no matter which condition becomes true). Also the code doesnt correspond to your issue description; if you click another div all other divs get black exept the clicked. It would be better if you grant access to your page to look for it